# How to import filtered excel table into python?

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel table, it looks like

[image]

Then, I created a filter on the column Sex to get all the female data, it looks like:

[image]

Then, I want to import the filtered data into python. I used the following pandas command:

```
df = pd.read_excel(io="test.xlsx", sheetname="Sheet1")
print(df)
```

The problem is that I got the entire data:

```
   Id   Name  Age Sex
0   1    Tom   12   M
1   2  Silke   33   F
2   3   Olga   22   F
3   4    Tom   33   M
```

However, this is not what I want, I only want the filtered data:

```
   Id   Name  Age Sex
1   2  Silke   33   F
2   3   Olga   22   F
```

How can I do this with python?

---

**Notice:** The reason why I want to import the filtered data but not filter data in python, is because of the original excel data. The filters in the excel table are very complicated. It based not only on many columns but also thousands of different values. It will be a big problem if I filter the data in python.

Comment: this might be a dumb question but why not filter it in pandas? Alternatively, if you save the filtered table as a .csv from Excel, it should not be a problem to get this into Python.

Comment: an 'if' condition won't work here ?

Comment: @patrick The problem is original data is very large and the filter based on the values is very complicated, because there are a lot of columns and thousands values to be filtered.

Comment: I see. I thought you were just filtering on "Sex"

Comment: @PythonCharmer Do you mean 'if' condition in python? I have no problem with python. But I want import the filtered data from excel into python. Because the original table is large and the filter is very complicated to create.

Comment: Why not copying your filtered data into a new Excel file and reading them through [`openpyxl`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io)? The new copy is necessary since `openpyxl` cannot actually read filtered data (AFAIK). Also `Pandas` is fine.

Comment: @superciccio14 Thanks, you are right. May be this is the only solution at moment...

Comment: @xirururu I'm working to a complete solution. Stay tuned...

Comment: @xirururu I was wrong. Actually, you can use `openpyxl` to read filtered data. I'm writing a possible solution...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned earlier in comments, a very quick and dirty way to do the trick is copying your filtered data in a new Excel file (without any filter) and get data from such a file.

A more elegant and complete solution consists in using [`openpyxl`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/) to read filtered data.

First, install `openpyxl`

```
$ pip install openpyxl
```

Then, use a script like this one to read just visible data:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('foo.xlsx') # use the actual path of your workbook
ws = wb['Bar'] # use your sheet name instead of Bar

# iterate over all the rows in the sheet
for row in ws: 
    # use the row only if it has not been filtered out (i.e., it's not hidden)
    if ws.row_dimensions[row[0].row].hidden == False:
        print row # ...or do what you need
```

Note that `row` is a tuple of `Cell`s. Use the attribute `value` for accessing to each cell's value:

```
    if ws.row_dimensions[row[0].row].hidden == False:
        for cell in row:
            print cell.value
```

You can use that logic to get your values straight from the original filtered file.

PS: openpyxl provides also a cool [Pandas integration](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/pandas.html) out of the box.

Comment: How would you get the filtered data from an .ods file?
openpyxl provides no support for .ods

Comment: @floatingpurr. Is it possible to get the column name that is filtered like in the above example column sex. here is the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76384722/when-reading-an-excel-file-in-python-can-we-know-which-column-field-is-filtered/76384858#76384858

Comment: Yes, have you already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76417039/4820341) answer out?