# Why is my numpy mean outcome different from calculating the mean by excel?

Tags: python, excel, numpy, mean

So my dataset, aka "filtered_test.xlsx" contains a dataset of the information regarding some Hotels in the US with stuff like ratings. So I want to calculate the mean average ratings grouped by the hotel name. I already dropped variables that has 0 and 'NaN' values in the "filtered_test.xlsx" file. My code is as follows:

```
   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import seaborn as sns 

   from matplotlib import rcParams #for chart


   df = pd.read_excel("filtered_test.xlsx")

   #Creates the average hotel ratings by hotel name
   hotel_rating = df.groupby('name') ['reviews.rating'].mean().reset_index()
   hotel_rating.to_excel("hotel_ratings.xlsx", index = False)
   hotelRating_df = pd.read_excel("hotel_ratings.xlsx")
```

Basically my mean values from numpy do not correspond to its correct values when i use excel to calculate them.

An example:

[example from filtered excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYNfw.png) this image showing one hotel has one value which is 4. So shouldn't the mean hotel ratings in my hotel_ratings.xlsx be 4 for this hotel 'Extended Stay America'? but in the hotel_ratings.xlsx, the mean for this hotel is [numpy mean of said hotel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QKSh.png) not the same as what it should be...

how can i fix this....

Comment: Are you expecting that `pd.read_excel()` ignores rows in your file that are excluded by your Excel filters? It doesn't work like that unfortunately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002159/how-to-import-filtered-excel-table-into-python

Comment: Are you asking how to fix your Excel Workbook? It’s hard to know what to fix when we don’t know anything about you did.

Comment: @PaulH So im calculating the average ratings from a list of hotels. I grouped them by their hotel name to then get the mean() values of their review ratings. But the mean values are off.

Comment: That’s describing what you did, not showing. “Grouping” rows isn’t a precise term in Excel. Did you use a pivot a table? Did you use a formula? Which formula? Over which cells?

Comment: @PaulH Oh! sorry about that. In excel I just used the =AVERAGE() and i used the cells that contain the review ratings that are under the same hotel name. 
But some hotels only have 1 review rating so the mean value of the rating should be equals to the original review rating right? But somehow running the python code to calculate mean is not showing the correct value for these hotels.

Comment: Try using a pivot table in excel. You’re not meant to type in different ranges for each row of a calculated column. You probably made a mistake and there’s no way to troubleshoot that on stackovetflow with the information you’re providing

Comment: @PaulH Ohhh okay I get it now thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Applied filters in excel don't transfer to Python. Maybe what you're looking for is something closer to:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 

from matplotlib import rcParams #for chart


df = pd.read_excel("filtered_test.xlsx")
df.fillna(-1,inplace=True)#Replace null values with -1
valid_ratings = df[df['reviews.rating']>-1] #Filter out rows that have their rating as -1
#if you want to filter out zeros, just change fillna and valid_ratings to use 0

#Creates the average hotel ratings by hotel name
hotel_rating = valid_ratings.groupby('name') ['reviews.rating'].mean().reset_index()
hotel_rating.to_excel("hotel_ratings.xlsx", index = False)
hotelRating_df = pd.read_excel("hotel_ratings.xlsx")
```